# How can I make this show the bluetooth devices list?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I want to list available Bluetooth devices and found this code in another question
I try to test it but it does not work

mainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    private BluetoothAdapter BA;
    private ArrayList<String> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.devicesList);

        BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        BA.startDiscovery();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                mDeviceList.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                Log.i("BT1", device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDeviceList));
            }
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }


}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/devicesList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

It looks like this on my phone
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHtqH.jpg)

Is there anything else I should do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Solved now, a kind predecessor helped me.
Maybe it's because of the system version
The old code worked for the old version of Android
And for new version try to add these ask for permission

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        permissionRequire();
...
```

```
 private void permissionRequire() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    }
```